# Importing Client object from discord.js does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

So I made a dashboard for a discord bot and was trying to get the guilds, however it gave the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache')
    at getManageableGuilds (e:\The House Party 2\Panzer Bot\dashboard\middleware.js:34:35)
    at module.exports.updateGuilds (e:\The House Party 2\Panzer Bot\dashboard\middleware.js:9:33)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

I am trying to use `client.guilds.cache.get(id)` to get the guilds but this does not seem to work, i also tried using `fetch` but that did not work either. I already tried fixing it with ChatGPT without any result. I am pretty sure I defined the client object correctly:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates
    ]
});
client.login(TOKEN);
module.exports = client;
```

This is what my middleware.js looks like, the `updateGuilds` part works fine but the `getManageableGuilds` function is where I am gettings errors, `const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(id)`:

```js
const authClient = require('./auth-client')
const client = require('../main')

module.exports.updateGuilds = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const key = res.cookies.get('key')
        if(key) {
            const authGuilds = await authClient.getGuilds(key)
            res.locals.guilds = getManageableGuilds(authGuilds)
        } 
    } finally {
        next()
    }
}


module.exports.updateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const key = res.cookies.get('key')
        if(key) res.locals.user = await authClient.getUser(key)
    } finally {
        next()
    }
}

module.exports.validateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.user ? next() : res.render('errors/401')
}

async function getManageableGuilds(authGuilds) {
    const guilds = [];
    for(const id of authGuilds.keys()){
        const isManager = authGuilds
            .get(id).permissions
            .includes('MANAGE_GUILD');
        const guild = await client.guilds.cache.get(id)
        if (!guild || !isManager) continue;

        guilds.push(guild);
    }
    return guilds;
}
```

I ended up fixing it by instead of importing the client I just decided to create a new client object, and doing `client.login(TOKEN)`. But having to do this in every single file that needs to use the client object from discordjs feels very unoptimized/buggy. Or is it fine to do so, if not; how else do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you're using the `Client` class from `discord.js` to get guild data? You don't need to do this, especially because every `client.login(TOKEN)` call starts up another Discord client that keeps a persistent WebSocket connection to and continuously receives guild events from Discord, which might slow down your Express app (depending on how big your bot is, of course).

Instead of using `discord.js` consider using their sub-packages `@discordjs/core` and `@discordjs/rest`. You already have these installed as `discord.js` depends on them. Here's how you can get guild data:

```js
// Assuming `TOKEN` and `id` are defined elsewhere

import { REST } from '@discordjs/rest';
import { GuildsAPI } from '@discordjs/core';

const rest = new REST().setToken(TOKEN);
const guilds = new GuildsAPI(rest);

const guild = await guilds.get(id);
```

If you're using CommonJS instead of ESM modules in your project, replace the `import` statements above with `require` syntax:

```js
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { GuildsAPI } = require('@discordjs/core');
```

Note though that the types of objects you get from `@discordjs/core` aren't the same as `discord.js`. Read the [documentation on `@discordjs/core`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/core/main) to learn more about it. https://discord-api-types.dev might help out too.